# ReactJS - Child unable to access parent state after update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-hooks

I have an `input field` in a child component that is prefilled from the value of a parent's state.

Since I pass the current value to the child as a prop and a function to update this value in the parent, it seems that whenever I update the parent from the passed function, my child is suddenly not able to access the parent state.

My parent's state:

```
  const [blockList,setBlockList] = useState({
    "0":{
      type:"loading",
      content:{
        'title':"placeholder_title",
        'description':"placeholder_description"
      }
    },
    "1":{
      type:"description",
      content:{
        'title':"placeholder_title",
        'description':"placeholder_description"
      }
    },
    "2":{
      type:"skills_and_requirements",
      content:{
        'title':"",
        'description':""
      }
    },
  })
```

The function passed to the child:

```
const _getBlockContent = (
  currentBlockKey, 
  contentKey, 
  returnedContent
) => {
  setBlockList(blockList[currentBlockKey].content[contentKey] = returnedContent)
}
```

What I pass to the child:

```
  return (    
      <Child
        currentBlock={blockList[selectedBlock]} // (i.e. selectedBlock = '1')
        _getBlockContent={_getBlockContent}
        currentBlockKey={selectedBlock} // (i.e. selectedBlock = '1')
      /> )
```

Now, whenever I save the input in the child and use the function `_getBlockContent` to update the state of my parent, this causes my Child to break.

```
TypeError: props.currentBlock.content is undefined
```

Full child (draftJS) :

```
const EditorPanel = (props) => {

  //receives the block from the parent. The block type will define the advice and other static elements of the pannel. The block content will define what to include in the input and editor fields.
  //This function should be passed to the editor and update the block content. 
  const _getEditorContent = (contentKey, returnedContent) => {
    console.log("contentKey is: %s", contentKey);
    console.log("returnedContent is: %s", returnedContent);
    props._getBlockContent(props.currentBlockKey,contentKey, returnedContent)
  }

  return(
    <div className="edit_panel">
      <div className="edit_panel_container">
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <MyEditor 
          contentKey={'title'}
          contentValue={props.currentBlock.content['title']}
          _getEditorContent={_getEditorContent}
        />
        <p>Title of this section should be eiusmod  dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
        <h3>Description</h3>
        <MyEditor 
          contentKey={'description'}
          contentValue={props.currentBlock.content['description']}
          _getEditorContent={_getEditorContent}
        />

        <p
        >Title of this section should be eiusmod  dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
        <p>Title of this section should be eiusmod  dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
      stateFromHTML(props.contentValue)
    )};
    this.onChange = editorState => {
      this.setState({editorState});
      //this.returnEditorHTML()
    }
    this.handleKeyCommand = this.handleKeyCommand.bind(this);
    this.focus = () => this.editor.focus();
    this.returnEditorHTML = editorState => {
      const content = stateToHTML(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent());
      props._getEditorContent(props.contentKey,content);
    };
  }



  handleKeyCommand(command, editorState) {
    const newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(editorState, command);

    if (newState) {
      this.onChange(newState);
      return 'handled';
    }

    return 'not-handled';
  }

  _onBoldClick() {
    this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, 'BOLD'));
  }

  _onItalicClick() {
    this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, 'ITALIC'));
  }

  _onUnderlineClick() {
    this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(this.state.editorState, 'UNDERLINE'));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="draft_input">
          <Editor 
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
            onChange={this.onChange} 
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this._onItalicClick.bind(this)}>I<i className="fas fa-bold"></i></button>
        <button onClick={this._onBoldClick.bind(this)}>B</button>
        <button onClick={this._onUnderlineClick.bind(this)}>U</button>
        <button onClick={this.returnEditorHTML}>save</button>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of Child JS, for completeness.

Comment: @RamGrandhi thanks! I've added the full child below my initial post.

Comment: @RamGrandhi There are actually 2 levels from the main parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `_getBlockContent` function, you replace the entire state with `returnedContent`, whereas instead you need to replace just the key you want to update:

```
const _getBlockContent = (
  currentBlockKey, 
  contentKey, 
  returnedContent
) => {
  const newBlockList = {
    ...blockList,
    [currentBlockKey]: {
        ...blockList[currentBlockKey],
        [contentKey]: returnedContent,
    }
  };
  setBlockList(newBlockList);
}
```

Since your `_getBlockContent` actually updates state, you should consider renaming it to something like `setBlockContent` or `onBlockContentChanged` to make it more clear than it is performing a write rather than a read

Answer (score 0):

I see something.

Going by your naming, `_getBlockContent(..)` is meant for retrieving the state.
Please note, `setBlockList(..)` is not meant for reading the state, it is only used for updating the state. For reading the state, you can directly use `blockList` in your function component `_getBlockContent(..)` like below.

```
    return blockList[currentBlockKey].content[contentKey];
```

Besides that, to actively reproduce your error on my end, can you share a github link or something containing **all the components** in your logic (including < Editor > etc)?